# Iterating through subelements of a list

Tags: r, github

I have a list that I want to iterate through:

```
library(RCurl)
data <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/b6b934b39e3c3378c3b2/raw/9b1efe9340c5b1c8acfdc90741260d1d554b2af0/data")
pull <- dget(textConnection(data))
```

I can access an individual element like this:

```
pull$content[[1]]$filename
```

But I want to access all the elements (e.g. `[[2]]@filename`, `[[3]]$filename`, etc.). I think this should do it:

```
n <- list(1:length(pull$content))
output <- list(1:length(n))
for (i in n){
  output[[i]] <- pull$content[[i]]$filename
}
```

However, it returns `Error in pull$content[[n]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I return the list properly?

Comment: @MrFlick: I think there is an error in your code `Error: unexpected '[[' in "sapply(pull$content, [["` and I don't know how to change it to make it run...

Comment: I fixed that. The "smart" formatting changed my quotes. But i see now that you're pulling a string that contains a structure. Rather than `write/dget` to disc, you can do `pull<-dget(textConnection(data))`

Comment: Yes, that seems to work, if you want to post it as an answer I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more idiomatic way of extracting all the `filename` values would be

```
sapply(pull$content, "[[", "filename")
```

This is because in most cases

```
obj$prop
obj[["prop"]]
```

return the same thing, but the latter form allows you to pass character values for the value you want to extract where as it's harder to dynamically extract different values with the `$` syntax. So basically we're calling the `[[` extract function on each of the `content` values and are requesting the `filename` value.

But your specific error message is generated because you have placed your indexes in a list

```
n <- list(1:length(pull$content))
length(n)
# [1] 1
```

Note that this a list of length 1 that contains the vector 1:30. This means your loop will only iterate once, and when it does, `i` will be `1:30`. That means that it will try to do

```
pull$content[[1:30]]$filename
```

which throws the recursive indexing error. This is because when you pass a vector to `[[`, rather than extracting multiple lists, it descents a lists of lists looking for particular indexes. For example

```
a <- list(list(9,list(list(7,6,list(4)), 8), 10))
a[[1]][[2]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
# [1] 4
a[[c(1,2,1,3,1)]]
# [1] 4
```

So it takes the first index of `a`, then the second index of the resulting list, then the first index of the resulting list, etc. That's where the "recursive" part is coming form.